# Array of the DateTime object

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

Why all the dates in array are the same? var_dump works OK

```
$start = new DateTime('01-01-2014');
$end = new DateTime('07-01-2014');
$dates = array();

do {
var_dump($start);
array_push($dates, $start);
$start->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day'));
}
while ($start != $end);

print_r($dates);
```

http://ideone.com/XV9I4C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because start is still the same object instance in every element of the array: you're pushing multiple pointers to the same instance, not multiple instances

```
$start = new DateTime('01-01-2014');
$end = new DateTime('07-01-2014');
$dates = array();

do {
var_dump($start);
array_push($dates, clone $start);
$start->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day'));
}
while ($start != $end);

print_r($dates);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/b71bZj)

Answer (score 0):

The array you create contains multiple references to the same object (the one you created with `$start = new DateTime('01-01-2014');`, thus they are all the same. `var_dump` only works because it outputs the current date of the objects.